# Is a data transfer from EC2 to an ECS repository a data transfer OUT?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I need to build a docker image and send it to an ECS repository.
Because my company's internet access is quite poor, I'm using an EC2 to achieve this.

I call `docker push` on the EC2, so I believe it may work similar as it is mentionned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40137778/using-aws-cli-from-ec2-instance-without-internet-access) with the cli.

My question is :  As I am on the same AWS account and region, is my image transfer using `docker push` considered an external or an internal transfer ?

This has an impact on both speed and [pricing](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/pricing/on-demand/?nc1=h_ls).

Comment: When you say ECS repository, do you mean Amazon ECR (https://aws.amazon.com/ecr/)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you mean building a docker image on a EC2 and then pushing to ECR.  After this the ECS cluster will pull the image and run as a container?

In this case, see this relevant [ECR FAQ](https://aws.amazon.com/ecr/faqs/) question from https://aws.amazon.com/ecr/faqs/

> Q: Is Amazon ECR a global service? Amazon ECR is a regional service
>   and is designed to give you flexibility in how images are deployed.
>   You have the ability to push/pull images to the same region where your
>   Docker cluster runs for the best performance. You can also access
>   Amazon ECR anywhere that Docker runs such as desktops and on-premises
>   environments. Pulling images between regions or out to the internet
>   will have additional latency and data transfer costs.

assuming that the EC2 with the cli on it and the EC2 with the ECS servers running on them are in the same zone and account then there is no charge

Remember that ECS is simply running on EC2..see the [ECS FAQ](https://aws.amazon.com/ecs/faqs/)

> Amazon Elastic Container Service (ECS) is a highly scalable, high
>   performance container management service that supports Docker
>   containers and allows you to easily run applications on a managed
>   cluster of Amazon EC2 instances

If they are in a different zone then there is a charge, even in the same account

See https://aws.amazon.com/govcloud-us/pricing/data-transfer/

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer. You made me realize that I was wrong with my question. I'm not using the cli at all. The cli is configured but the image is sent using the docker push command. I edited my question and specified that everything is in the same region. ECS is not a server hosted on an EC2 but a repository managed by AWS.

Comment: Yep, I confused ECS and ECR as I was accessing Repository (which seems to be ECR) from the ECS window. Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are referring to Amazon's Elastic Container Registry (ECR).

Th [ECR pricing page](https://aws.amazon.com/ecr/pricing/) indicates that "*Data transferred between Amazon Elastic Container Registry and Amazon EC2 within a single region is free of charge*".

Comment: ECS Repository seems to be ECR. You're right, I confused the two. Thanks.